# Get ClientContext using URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

In Sharepoint, when we load the sp.js file after that when we use given code then it gives the current site context.
But how can i get the site context using url.

```
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Comment: Can you helo me with this abut. Ihave exact same line, but it just don´t work. dev tool in Chrome says Uncaught errortype: undefined is not a function. ANy hint about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_current()` would always return current context only. If you want to get context of particular site then you would need to pass url in `ClientContext()` method.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(URL);
```

In case you want to get root site context then you can directly use `get_root()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  var context = new SP.ClientContext(URL);
```